# Bonus system based on %

Tags: if-statement, formula

I am seeking your assistance on a formula for a bonus system. 
The target minimum sales is 180,000 and I would like to calculate the bonus as follows:

```
under 180,000 = zero bonus
180,000 to 210,000 = 2% bonus of the sales 
210,000 and above = 4% bonus of sales
```

Therefore, if for example 250,000 is achieved, there is zero bonus for the amount under 180,000; 2% bonus on the 30,000 in between 180,000 and 210,000 and 4% on the 40,000 above 210,000 which will equal:

```
2% of 30,000  = 600
4% of 50,000 = 2000

Total bonus = 2600

I have tried to use some of the IF equations on this site, but cannot seem to work it out.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code first please

Comment: Specify your language plz...

Answer (score 0):

Take one variable say `int sal`; assign it the values and check like this yor `if-else` statement should look like this.

**EDIT**
Take on variable say `int bonus = 0`;

```
if(sal <= 18000) {
  // No Bonus  
  bonus = 0;    
} else if (sal > 18000 && sal < 21000) {
  // Do calculation for 2%
  bonus = (sal)*.02;
} else if(sal > 21000){
// Do calculation for 4%
   bonus = (sal)*.04;
}
```

This will give you the bonus amount as per salary in round off value.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. My apologies, but I am not so experienced on excel. How can I put this in a formula format. so assuming the base (180k) is in cell A1 and the the 2% is in cell A2; the 4% us in B1

Comment: As per your question it will give if sal = 40000 the the bonus = 1600

Comment: dont have experience with excel sheet http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/formula_begin_2.htm follow this link it would be help full

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - it's pseudo-code

```
maxSales = 10000000000000000000

def calcBonus(x, bonusSystem):
    totalBonus = 0
    lowBase = 0
    for hiBase, percentage in bonusSystem:
        if (lowBase < x):
            totalBonus += (min(x,hiBase) - lowBase) * percentage
            lowBase = hiBase
    return totalBonus

bonusSystem = [(180000, 0), (210000,.02), (maxSales, .05)]
sales = 250000
print calcBonus(sales, bonusSystem)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. My apologies, but I am not so experienced on excel. How can I put this in a formula format. so assuming the base (180k) is in cell A1 and the the 2% is in cell A2; the 4% us in B1.

Comment: if you'd mention you needed excel formula I wouldn't answer. this is a pseudo-code for how to do the calculation you are asking in general